# Handler Android Studio

Tags: java, android, handler

I have a handler in android app and this works realy good

Down is the code for my handler

```
Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            downloadusernamelist();
            isInternetWorking();
            syncDataSftp();
        }finally {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
        }}};
```

Now this handler is on launcher activity and when i go to next activity and go back to first launcher activity the handler starts again...

How can i make that the handler not restarts every time i go back to first activity?

Comment: Do you know life cycle of activity?

Comment: If the above code is not in on Create Method, please try putting it in on Create Method of your activity Lifecycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a boolean such as;

```
private boolean firstTime = true;
```

Then you can decide on starting the handler according to firstTime boolean value.

```
if(firstTime){
   runHandler();
   firstTime = false;
}
```

You should also save firstTime value onSaveInstance and restore that value onCreate;